# Manhattan distance algorithm job interview question

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of *n* points in an X-Y plane, how can I determine if every point is at least separated by every other point by a Manhattan distance of 5 units in time less than O(n^2)?

What is the best algorithm to implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a question but an assignment.

Comment: How do you know that's an assignment? This easily is an interview question.

Comment: @arasmussen, "assignment" does not necessarily mean homework. My point is that the OP did not ask a question.

Comment: Good point. Zaya, what work have you done on this question so far? What are your thoughts? What does it mean for the algorithm that it is less than O(n^2)?

Comment: @arasmussen I totally agree with Bart. I think you didn't get his point. What he meant is that the sentence given by zaya is an assignment (order). It is written in imperative form. It is not a question asking something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sort the points by `x`.  This takes time 'O(n log(n))'.
2. Divide the range into strips of width 10.  (You'll need an obvious bit of care here for the pathological case where one point has x-coordinate 1 and the next has x-coordinate 10<sup>20</sup>.)  `O(n)`
3. For each strip:

   1. Take the set of points within that strip, or within an x of 5 to either side, and sort them by y.  This is `O(n log(n))` across all strips.
   2. For each point in the strip, find the Manhattan distance to all other points in that slightly wider strip whose y coordinate is within 5 of their own.  If you find any within distance 5, exit and report false.  This is `O(n)` across all strips.
4. Report true.

This algorithm is `O(n log(n))`.  I strongly advise that you demonstrate for yourself that the pointwise Manhattan comparison in 1.2 takes `O(n)` operations, *even* if the answer is false.

For true it is simple - it follows from the fact that there is a maximum number of other points that can be squeezed in a 20x10 box without 2 getting within 5.  For false it is trickier, you can have a lot of other points in that box, but by the time you have compared a fixed number of them to the rest, you must have found two within distance 5.  Either way a given point participates in a fixed maximum number of point to point comparisons before you have your answer.

Comment: how is sorting by y for all strips O(n)?  Using radix sort?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but since you have up to n strips, sorting each of those strips by y results in n * (n log(n)) operations, meaning n^2 log(n). Am I wrong? I recognize that in practice it will be a much diminished set (i.e. if there are many strips, then the values in each are limited, so the internal sorting is smaller; if there are few strips then there are few sorts) so it should be fast, but it still technically seems n^2 log(n) to me...

Comment: @DRobinson If there are `n` strips, then each sort is `O(1)`.  In general if you have `k` lists and `n` things between them, sorting all `k` lists cannot be worse than sorting `n` things with up to `k` labels by label and then by thing, so no matter how many lists there are it is no worse than `O(n log(n))` to sort them all.

Comment: Yes, but take for example a situation where there is n/2 strips, two of which each have about n/4 elements (the remaining n/2 elements are distributed among the remaining (n/2 - 2) strips). Is this not, technically, going over O(n) strips (because there are n/2 of them), and in each sorting O(n) [because worst case has n/4 -> O(n)] values? That would be O(n/2 * O(n/4 log(n/4)) = O(n * nlog(n)). Obviously it will be much faster but in pure big O that still seems like n^2log(n) to me.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, which, again, is entirely possible.

Comment: @DRobinson You are confusing yourself with the notation.  The number of comparisons needed to sort `n` things with a merge sort is bounded above by `n lg(n)` where `lg(n)` is the base 2 logarithm of `n` rounded up.  Play around with concrete numbers.  You'll find that there is no way to divide `n` things among `k` lists such that sorting each list takes more comparisons than it would if you put them all into one list.  That's a concrete `O(n log(n))` bound on the work in this case.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the conceptual error you're making.  I believe it is this.  Big-O is simply a notation for worst case.  You derived a `O(n * n * log(n))` upper bound.  That upper bound is true.  But it says nothing about whether there might be a sharper upper bound.  In this case there is.